# Build a multiplatform JDK/Tomcat docker image to be able to run on Apple Silicon

Tags: java, docker, tomcat, apple-m1, apple-silicon

We build docker images with tomcat services within our CI as follows:

```
- PLATFORMS: linux/amd64,linux/arm64/v8
- gradle build …
# Switch to use different docker driver which supports multiplatform builds
- docker buildx create --use
- docker buildx build --push --platform=$PLATFORMS -t $image -f infra/Dockerfile .
```

This works and pushes the image which can easily be run on linux/amd64 platforms.

However when running this image on Apple Silicon, it fails with:

```
org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig
Failed to detect ServletContainerInitializers for context with name [] service 
java.net.MalformedURLException: no !/ found in url spec:file:/usr/local/tomcat/lib/tomcat-websocket.jar!/META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer
```

Full stack trace here: https://gist.github.com/knyttl/c8f2c24ac3d94a91911ca08f08eff668

What surprises me a bit is:

```
org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener Architecture:          amd64
```

I guess the architecture should be `linux/arm64/v8`, so why does it run the wrong one?

Comment: The problem could be that your system/ci service is unable to build the image for the desired architecture , `linux/arm64/v8`, and when it runs in Apple Silicon is fails because it tries running a wrong one, the `amd64`. It is the same problem described in [this post](https://githubhot.com/repo/kartoza/docker-geoserver/issues/307) and [related issue](https://github.com/postgis/docker-postgis/issues/216). If you run [`docker buildx inspect --bootstrap`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_inspect/), does the system report the `linux/arm64/v8` as available?

Comment: HI, the `inspect` command reports only `Platforms: linux/amd64, linux/386` – does it mean we will not be able to build for apple sillicon in our CI? Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: Hi @VVojtěch. Thank you for the feedback. I am not aware about tha actual CI product you are using but, afaik, if the output of the inspect command doesn't contain the necessary platform you will be unable to build images for that platform. Please, could you provide more information about the type of CI system that you are using? As you can read in the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/buildx/working-with-buildx/#build-multi-platform-images), the actual build process greatly depends on  underlying requirements (QEMU, binfmt_misc).  ....

Comment: There is a [great post](https://nexus.eddiesinentropy.net/2020/01/12/Building-Multi-architecture-Docker-Images-With-Buildx/) that describes these components, derived from a related, although old, [Github issue](https://github.com/docker/buildx/issues/208). In any way, `buildx` is a complicated subject: I think the problem is the one stated but honestly I am unaware of all the different configuration options, perhaps some of them could be of help. I hope any of the provided information helps and you managed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I abandoned the CI way of building M1 images.

Instead, I have written a bash script (to be run locally on M1) which extracts the CI-built image and rebuilds an M1 image with the CI-built image contents. Not exactly nice, but it works.